# Scratch card probabilities

Tags: probability

A scratch card is in the form of a 5 x 5 matrix. Scratching any square reveals a sum of money. The sums available are 4 x 2.50 dollars, 9 x 1.00 dollar, 12 x 0.50 dollar.

When the scratch card was made it was agreed to place the 2.50 values in the 4 corners. This is not known to the players. The remaining values are randomly distributed over the remaining 21 squares. The idea of the card is to scratch open squares until at least 4.00 dollars in total has been reached. The table below indicates the probability of uncovering at least 4.00 in total, by scratching respectively 1 or 2 or…….8 squares open. For example the probability of uncovering at least a total of 4.0 by scratching 3 squares is 0.287. The probability of needing to scratch 8 squares open to get to the 4.00 total would mean first scratching 7 squares with $0.50\square followed by a 2.50 or 1.00 or another 0.50 dollars to make up the 8 squares. Necessary and sufficient for this last case would seem to be 7 x 0.50 squares as the last square can take on any of the 3 values, giving a probability of
(12C7)/(25C7) = 0.00165. If however you take all 8 into account, this gives:

(12C8)/(25C8) + [(12C7)(9C1)]/(25C8) + [(12C7)(4C1)]/(25C8) = 0.009977 ??

What am I doing wrong here?

I also cannot confirm the 0.287, 0.230, 0.215, and 0.202 values below!

The probability for 7 squares is blank. I cannot format the table properly as I am unfamiliar the applicable text editor.

Number of squares   1 2 3   4   5   6   7   8

Probability 0   0.020   0.287   0.230   0.215   0.202       0.002

Comment: Instructions for formatting the mathematics, including tables, are at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of calculation is very similar to computing Shapley values (see below), which is generally a very messy thing. A convenient way to organize the calculation is as follows. First, compute in units of $50$-cent pieces; thus there are $12$ squares of value $1$, $9$ of value $2$, and $4$ of value $5$. To compute the number of "ways" (sequences of choices) which surpass the goal of $8$ on the $k$-th move, note that the first $k-1$ moves must give a total between $3$ and $7$, so start with a partition of a number in that range into $k-1$ parts, with each part being $1$, $2$, or $5$. There will in general be a number of permutations of these; let $s$ be that number of permutations. Finally, choose a $k$-th move which puts us over the goal. If $a_i$ denotes the number of spaces with value $i$ we have used, then the number of sequences of choices thus accounted for is
$$s 12^\underline{a_1}\,9^\underline{a_2}\,4^\underline{a_5},$$
where $x^\underline{k}$ denotes the falling power $x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)$. We sum over all partitions, and choices for the final move, to get the total number of ways to take $k$ moves; dividing the result by $25^\underline{k}$ gives the probability.

For example, with $k=4$, there are five relevant partitions: $(1,1,5)$, $(1,1,1)$, $(1,1,2)$, $(1,2,2)$, $(2,2,2)$. Taking the first partition as an example, it can be permuted in $3$ ways, and the fourth move can have value $1$, $2$, or $5$ (and there would be $10$, $9$, or $3$ ways to pick the fourth move respectively). Thus this partition contributes
$$3\cdot 12\cdot11\cdot4\cdot(10+9+3)=34,848$$
to the overall count. Adding this up for all five partitions gives $69,792$ ways to win in exactly four moves, a probability of $69,792/25^{\underline{4}}=0.2299$.

Carrying this out gives the following probabilities of requiring $k$ moves, for $k=2,\ldots,8$:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
k&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
\hline
p&\frac{1}{50}&\frac{33}{115}&\frac{1454}{6325}&\frac{1362}{6325}&\frac{1629}{8050}&\frac{3351}{76475}&\frac{18}{10925}\\
&0.02& 0.2870& 0.2299& 0.2153& 0.2024& 0.0438& 0.0016\\
\end{array}$$
(which do indeed add up to $1$, a good check.)

Essentially as a corollary to this calculation, we can compute the Shapley values of the three denominations. That is, for each denomination ($\$0.50$, $\$1.00$, and $\$2.50$), compute the probability that the square which puts us over the $\$4.00$ goal has that denomination, and divide by the number of squares with that denomination. We just group the calculations we did by the final denomination, rather than by the number of squares. We find that the Shapley values are $\$0.497684$, $\$0.979435$, and $\$2.55322$ respectively; that is, a $\$2.50$ square is actually worth slightly more than face value, and the others are worth slightly less.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between these two events:

- uncovering a total of at least $4$ by scratching $N$ squares;
- *needing* to scratch $N$ squares to uncover a total of at least $4$.

The first event occurs, but the second does *not* occur,
if you scratch $N$ squares and the
first $N-1$ squares already have a total of $4$ or more.

The probabilities in the table are clearly
probabilities of the second kind of event,
so the order in which the squares are revealed matters.
When you write $\binom{12}{7} \binom91 / \binom{25}{8}$, for example,
that is the probability of scratching $7$ squares of value $0.5$ and
one square of value $1$ *in any sequence.*
But only in the case where the square of value $1$ is opened *last*
do you need $8$ squares to get a total of $4$ or more. In every other
case the total of $4$ is reached when the seventh square is opened.

Your calculation of the probability for $8$ squares therefore
overestimates the probability by including events that are not part
of the event you are supposed to measure.

In order to need to open $8$ squares,
it is necessary that all $7$ of the first $7$ opened squares
must have value $0.5$ each. The probability of that is 
$\binom{12}{7} / \binom{25}{7}$.
If that happens, then the eighth square will certainly bring the
total to $4$ or more, so a correct way to take into account
the eighth square is to multiply by $1$.
The final result (and the correct probability that you need
to open $8$ squares) is
$$
\frac{\binom{12}{7}}{\binom{25}{7}} \times 1 
= \frac{\binom{12}{7}}{\binom{25}{7}} \approx 0.0016476.
$$

---

If you *must* consider three separate cases depending on whether
the last square opened has value $0.5$, $1$, or $2.5$, then a
correct expression for the probability is
$$
\frac{\binom{12}{8}}{\binom{25}{8}}
+ \frac{\binom{12}{7}}{\binom{25}{7}} \times \frac{\binom91}{\binom{18}{1}}
+ \frac{\binom{12}{7}}{\binom{25}{7}} \times \frac{\binom41}{\binom{18}{1}},
$$
which happens to be exactly ${\binom{12}{7}}/{\binom{25}{7}}$;
in other words, we get the same result as before,
but make the calculation quite a bit more complicated than
this particular probability requires.

Comment: If I am following you correctly, this should mean that the equation above should be rewritten as 12C8)/(25C8) + [(12C7)(1C1)]/(25C8) + [(12C7)(1C1)]/(25C8) = 0.001923

Comment: No, it means the probability is really $0.00165$ after all. An expression such as $\binom{12}{7}\binom11/\binom{25}{8}$ still fails to take into account the fact that the "$1$" square must be chosen last.

Comment: Both answers above are great, however I seem to be able to Green-arrow only one?

Comment: The important thing is that you accept _one_ of the answers if your question has been adequately answered. You made a good choice.

Comment: Despite the fact that the site advises not to offer thanks in the comments section, I would still like to express my sincere thanks to both of you for this help. It really has given me new insights w.r.t. the problem discussed.